# How to change recipient of a VACATION autoresponder mail to one in sender's mail header section [Reply-to] purely in Sieve Language?

Tags: email, sieve-language

I need to set an autoresponder that will send a message like "We got You mail! We will get back to you ASAP". The problem is that the sender of customer email is not customer itself (i.e. customer@privatemail.com), but some global mail  (i.e. customerservice@marketplace.com) that contains customer private mail in the header section [Reply-to].

This is a hosted server with installed RoundCube. I can only use Sieve filters to create an autoresponder.

```
rule:[Autoresponder]
if allof (
header :contains "from" "@marketplace.pl", 

{
    vacation text:
    We got You mail! We will get back to you ASAP!
.
;
}
```

I need to read the value of the header [Reply-To] section, set the recipient of autoresponder mail to that value and send a VACATION message. Only in Sieve language.

Comment: Do you know which Sieve extensions are installed on the server, or which Sieve implementation the server is using?

Comment: No. I now that is using RoundCube and DirectAdmin. I have no data about mail server nor sieve version